# How can I make rounded rectangle Maskable icon for PWA without background?

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I tried to generated maskable icon for my Reactjs PWA app with maskable.app => select "Rounded Rectangle" => Export but the app icon added on the home screen always appears to have background color fill outside the rounded rectangle app icon.

Something like this:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

Is there any way to achieve this? Or that's how PWA works?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any control over how maskable icons are cropped on an operating system. They're designed to be safe to crop into any shape, and maskable.app lets you preview different shapes.

However, not every operating system uses maskable icons. On Windows (which seems to be the operating system used in your screenshots), the `"purpose": "any"` icon is used instead. You can upload a separate, non-maskable icon that has transparency and is cropped however you like.

Your Web App Manifest would have something like this:

```
"icons": [
    {
        "purpose": "any",
        "src": "rounded_rectangle_icon.png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
        "purpose": "maskable",
        "src": "maskable_icon.png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
    }
]
```